# Hide .html in url

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, hide

I want to hide .html from url, example www.site.com/videos.html to www.site.com/videos. I looked for similar questions here but with no result.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos.html$ category.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos-([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ category.php?cat=$1&page=$2&sortby=$3

RewriteRule ^register.html$ register.php
RewriteRule ^contact_us.html$ contact_us.php
RewriteRule ^edit_profile.html$ edit_profile.php
RewriteRule ^suggest.html$ suggest.php
RewriteRule ^upload.html$ upload.php
RewriteRule ^upload_avatar.html$ upload_avatar.php
RewriteRule ^suggest.html$ suggest.php

RewriteRule ^favorites.html(.*)$ favorites.php$1
RewriteRule ^login.html(.*)$ login.php$1
RewriteRule ^newvideos(.*)$ newvideos.php$1
RewriteRule ^topvideos.html(.*)$ topvideos.php$1
RewriteRule ^profile.html(.*)$ profile.php$1
RewriteRule ^favorites.html(.*)$ favorites.php$1
RewriteRule ^playlist/(.*)$ myfavorites.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^memberlist.html(.*)$ memberlist.php$1

RewriteRule ^articles/read-(.*)_([0-9]+).html$ article_read.php?a=$2
RewriteRule ^articles/index-([0-9]+).html$ article.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^articles/browse-(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ article.php?c=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^articles/tag/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)(/)?$ article.php?tag=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^articles/tag/([^/]+)(/)?$ article.php?tag=$1&page=1
RewriteRule ^articles/popular-([0-9]+).html$ article.php?show=popular&page=$1
RewriteRule ^articles(\/|.html)?$ article.php
RewriteRule ^article(\/|.html)?$ article.php
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)\.html$ page.php?name=$1

RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/$ tag.php?t=$1&page=1
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)(/)?$ tag.php?t=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-video_(.*).html$ watch.php?vid=$2
RewriteRule ^fpembed-(.*).swf$ fpembed.php?vid=$1
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ rss.php [L]</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect the client from `videos.html` to `videos`

```
RewriteRule ^/?videos.html$ /videos
```

this requires, that `/videos` is a valid URL.

Comment: I changed `^topvideos.html(.*)$ topvideos.php$1` with `^topvideos$ topvideos.php$1` and work but redirects me at /topvideos.html not /topvideos

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]